# Is it possible to use same modem firmware on different phones?

Tags: custom-roms, mobile-network, micromax-yu-yuphoria

Can I flash a modem file of a phone to another model? If we can't flash the modem file can you tell me what hardware or software the modem file depend so that it is different for different phone?

You might be wondering why I want to flash modem file even if everything is working fine is that I got volte by using this [method](http://forums.yuplaygod.com/threads/how-to-get-volte-in-yuphoria-yu5010-yu5010a.42275/).

As login is required to view the link I will explain how I got volte. I download the firmware of yuphoria 5010a which is mostly similar to my phone's specifications. And also downloaded the stock rom of yuphoria 5010a. After that I flashed firmware, rom on my phone using fastboot. I then updated the volte patch which the phone manufacturer released for that phone and installed it and I got volte working on my device.

But the only downside was that I am only able to use volte with 32 bit rom not the 64 bit rom.

Also can you tell me how to clone or backup my entire device (including the critical file such as modem, boot,etc) so that while I would be doing lot of fiddling I can restore my device to its current state without losing anything including the volte which I obtained by flashing the modem file?

My Device : Yu Yuphoria
(5010)

ROM : MIUI 8.1(android 5.1)

Comment: Flashing a modem file (firmware) from a different device is bad... potentially very bad, the chances it will work are near zero and do anything from cause connectivity issues to a complete bricking of the device. I tried to look at your link but it just errors out, but suffice it to say that anyone who recommends flashing radios from a different device needs to be considered with great skepticism.

Comment: @acejavelin The link is working but login was required to view the link. I have updated my question with the steps involved in the process.

Comment: @acejavelin Both the devices had something in common due to which I was able to use the modem file on my device. Why would be the hardware due to which different devices have different modem file?

Comment: Modems are unique to the hardware as implemented by the manufacturer, and the kernel, and other device specific settings... If you found two devices that use the same modem firmware interchangably, you hit a 1 in a million chance and won.

Answer (score 2):

**No, you can't** flash firmware designed to work with one android device to another one.

There are some bizzare situations where this does work because devices have identical hardware (Coolpad F1 and Micromax A310), but this is very unlikely to happen and you shouldn't try it.

As for a device backup, you can make a nandroid backup using CWM or TWRP and copy it to your computer.

Answer (score 0):

> If we can't flash the modem file can you tell me what hardware or software the modem file depend so that it is different for different phone?

**Modem** itself is hardware, so which modem file (firmware) is to be used depends on modem. Usually it's embedded with SoC - the central chip which contains CPU, RAM and other critical components. So if two phones have same modem, there are chances the same firmware works for both. Most of the times same modem means same SoC - it's [Snapdragon 410](https://www.qualcomm.com/products/snapdragon-processors-410) on your device.

Modem has its own processor called baseband (BP), totally isolated from Android OS which runs on Application Processor (AP) - the one we usually call CPU. In userspace telephony stack (Java) talks to RILD (native vendor specific binary blob) which depends on Linux kernel for communication with modem. Kernel has special implementation from OEM/SoC vendor to create communication channel between AP and BP.

Additionally the firmware may also contain software related to other components interacting with BP like Digital Signal Processor (DSP), SIM card and SIM reader etc. So all of the relevant details must be exactly identical on both phones for same firmware to work.